# MUI textfield hide native keyboard IOS Safari

Tags: css, ios, reactjs, material-ui

We have a use case, where we need to show an MUI text field and and a virtual keyboard to enter values. When the user focuses on the text field native keyboard should not pop up. But in mobile IOS safari browser keyboard popups. Is there a specific way to prevent native keyboards from popping up in mobile devices?